# If vector, v = (1,4) then find the matrix of perp v

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonal-matrices

Can anyone please help me with this problem.

A vector $\boldsymbol{v}$ is given with the coordinates $1, 4$

$\boldsymbol{v} = (1,4)$

Find the matrix of *perp* $\boldsymbol{v}$.

As far as I know *perp* $\boldsymbol{v}$ means the orthogonal compliment of $\boldsymbol{v}$.

I dont know how to find *perp* ***v***, but I know how to find the matrix if two vectors are given. Can anyone please help me out? Please be gentle, I'm very new to linear algebra ^-^

**EDIT: I see a lot of people are asking if I stated the problem correctly.**

[Well, I have finally taken a picture of the question from my book. Hope this clears up all confusions and doubts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QUKr.jpg)

If it helps the answer is given as:

1/17 (16    -4)
     (-4     1) .  Its a matrix, sorry if I couldnt write the mathematical symbols correctly.

If it helps to understand the matrix more clearly, 1st coloumn of the matrix is (16, -4) second coloumn is (-4, 1) and the matrix is multiplied by 1/17 (a scalar)

But thats the answer. Could anyone please help me guide through the steps, to get to this answer? What does perpv mean here? Is it the same as an orthogonal compliment? How do I find the orthogonal compliments matrix?

Comment: Hint: Orthogonal vectors have a zero dot product.  Can you write down the formula for what a zero dot product means in terms of $\vec{u}=\langle a,b\rangle$ for the perpendicular vector?

Comment: You have a number of "inaccuracies" in your question.  To begin with, a single vector, such as v, does **not have** an "orthogonal complement", a vector *sub-space* has an orthogonal complement.  I presume you mean to find the orthogonal complement of the subspace spanned by v= <1, 4>.  As Michael Burr said, that consists of the space of all vectors u= <a, b> such that a+ 4b= 0.  We can write that as a= -4b so the orthogonal complement is the space of all vectors of the form <-4b, b>= b<-4, 1>, the subspace spanned by <-4, 1>.

Comment: a+4b=0, so b=-a/4

So all points of the form (a,-a/4) belongs to perp $v$.
It's a straight line

Comment: A matrix *perp **v*** sounds a bit strange to me. Are you sure of the statement of your problem? 
Are looking for ${\bf v}^{\perp}=\{{\bf w}\in\mathbb{R}^2:\langle{\bf v},{\bf w}\rangle=0\}$?

Answer (score 1):

A perpendicular matrix is just changing the entries of the vector, so that

\begin{align*}
A \cdot \vec{x} = A \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} x_2 \\ x_1 \end{pmatrix} \end{align*}

The perpendicular matrix is (I think in general):

\begin{align*}
A= \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} 
\end{align*}

A projection matrix just projects a vector on the zero (or the kernel):
\begin{align*}
A \cdot \vec{x} = 0\end{align*}

Now just write down the equations, I think you will mention that.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your input. But that still doesn't answer the question though. How do I find the matrix of perp v? The answer is 1/17 (16 -4) (-4 1) But I dont know the steps, or how to think when solving a problem like this. As you can see from the answer, there are a few negative entries in the matrix. Even if I do it like you said, you still don't get any negative entries in the matrix. I suspect it has something to do with the reflection. Like if a vector is (1,1) its reflection is (-1,1) 

This should really be a simple problem, but for some reason I cant wrap my head around it.